# Sweetalert confirm before delete in php

Tags: php, sweetalert

I want to use the confirmation alert of sweetalert. But I face some issues my code is not working when I click yes nothing happens even though I already call my delete function . My only problem is my SWAL regarding to my query all is working good. Now this is my code

This is my user_del.php

```
    <?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
header('Location:../index');
endif;
include("../dist/includes/dbcon.php");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE accounts_at SET status = 0 WHERE id ='$id'")
    or die(mysqli_error());
        if ($result !== false) {
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully archived a account!');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location='index'</script>";
    }

?>
```

```js
function archiveFunction(id) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }).then(function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
            window.location = 'user_del.php?id='+id;
        }
        else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
 <a id="removeme" onclick="archiveFunction(1)" href="#">Click to archived the data
</a>
```

Comment: My problem is not about redirect. The query is not executing it does nothing . Do I missed something on my code?

Comment: var_dump($result); after execution and do echo mysqli_info($con);

Comment: I'm confused . Because my archived function is on my index.php along with " <a id="removeme" onclick="archiveFunction(1)" href="#">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-red" title="Click to archived the data"></i>
</a>" now do I need to put on the same page all of my codes?

Comment: explain one thing ! after your click browser redirect to "user_del.php?id=123" page right? or it redirected to index page ?

Comment: Yes it redirect to index page

Comment: @amaraaaaa Man.., it is because of php session is not created in previous controller or page ,create session before page submitting or change condition to if(empty($_GET['id'])):
header('Location:../index');
endif;

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using $_REQUEST,

since you are using `window.location = 'user_del.php?id='+id;` GET METHOD, you need to use $_GET to get the id

Please try this on **user_del.php**

```
<?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
header('Location:../index');
endif;
include("../dist/includes/dbcon.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE accounts_at SET status = 0 WHERE id ='$id'")
    or die(mysqli_error());
        if ($result !== false) {
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully archived a account!');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location='index'</script>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I already use GET. But it does nothing. Did I missed something?

Comment: @amaraaaa how about to change from $result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE accounts_at SET status = 0 WHERE id ='$id'") to $result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE accounts_at SET status = 0 WHERE id ='{$id}'")

Comment: I already change my query but it does nothing . In your opinion what is missing on my code?

Comment: try to do this? "UPDATE accounts_at SET status = 0 WHERE id ={$id}" @amaraaaa i think all is correct, the one that not correct is your table.